# Swift - how to declare variable/functon of/with enums of different type?

Tags: ios, swift, generics, enums, protocols

I need to declare variable which will store array of enums of different type, eg.:

```
var enums = [EnumTypeA.Option1, EnumTypeB.Option2]
```

Compiler states:

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

This will be necessary to pass any enum or other object as a function parameter. However I discovered that I can pass generics to achieve this, eg.:

```
func f1<T>(enum: T)
```

but having **protocol with optional methods** (prefixed with @objc) it is impossible.

Comment: You mention an @objc protocol, can tell us more about it and what role does have in what you're trying to do?

Comment: Using @objc protocols is immament to declare some of their functions as optional and using such delegates as weak properties.

Comment: What's conforming to such protocol in your example?

Comment: The request delegate with the callback methods described by the request type.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a protocol...

```
protocol MyEnums {}

enum MyEnum1: MyEnums {
    case first, second
}

enum MyEnum2: MyEnums {
    case red, green
}

let myArray: [MyEnums] = [MyEnum1.first, MyEnum2.green]

func myFunc(myEnum: MyEnums) {
    print(myEnum)
}

for value in myArray {
    myFunc(myEnum: value)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer for the first part of my question but the main task wasn't achieved because I **cannot narrow down** my protocol method **to parameters that conforms to your custom protocol**. Is has to be more generic.

Answer (score 1):

This was fun. Instead of generics, I just went with `Any`, since that is the base of everything.

```
enum TypeA {
    case Option1
    case Option2
}

enum TypeB {
    case Option1
    case Option2
}

func acceptDifferentEnums(value: Any) {
    switch value {
    case let typeA as TypeA:
        print("This is TypeA")
    case let typeB as TypeB:
        print("This is typeB")
    default:
        print("This is something else")
    }
}


acceptDifferentEnums(TypeA.Option1) // This is TypeA
acceptDifferentEnums(TypeB.Option2) // This is TypeB
acceptDifferentEnums("Foo") // This is something else
```

You then use the switch statement to downcast the `value` property into your various enums, and process them accordingly.

Comment: The problem is that you cannot use Any or generics  in the protocol with optional methods.